# Layout não esta se adequando corretamente em dispositivos mobile

Tags: css, media-queries

Usei uma Media Query para fazer um layout responsivo, que ficaria assim no desktop:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim no mobile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que quando entro no site utilizando o celular o layout não fica como deveria, ele utiliza o layout de desktop e não o de mobile, como resolvo?

A media query do desktop se encontra na linha 127 e a do mobile na linha 295

```css
/*
Estilos e fontes globais
*/

*
{
 margin: 0px;
}

html
{
 background-image: url("../Imagens/Fundo.jpg");
}

a:link 
{
 color: #ECEEF4; 
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited
{
 color: #F3DAF7;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
 color: #92369C;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.2s;
}

@font-face
{
 font-family: Another Danger;
 src: url("../Fontes/Another Danger.otf")
}

@font-face
{
 font-family: Potra;
 src: url(../Fontes/Potra.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
 font-family: earthorbitersemital;
 src: url(../Fontes/earthorbitersemital.ttf);
}

@font-face
{
 font-family: pdark; 
 src: url("../Fontes/pdark.ttf");
}

.Bar
{
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(../Imagens/BR1.png);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 font-family: Another Danger;
 color: #ECEEF4;
 font-size: 25px;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.sla2
{
 padding-top: 2.5%;
 padding-bottom: 4.5%;
}

#sla1
{
 background-image: url(../Imagens/Sobrefundo.png);
 background-size: 100% 110%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

#sla
{

 font-family: earthorbitersemital;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: white;

 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;

 padding-right: 13.4%;
 padding-left: 13.4%;

}

#Ti1
{
 font-family: earthorbitersemital;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#st5
{
 font-family: Potra;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color:#8EB8FC;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

 #Ti
 {
  font-family: Potra;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: white;
 }



/* 
Estilos unicos do desktop
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 751px)
{

 .TDs
 {
  background-image: url(../Imagens/Fundop.png);
  background-size: 80% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .stt
 {
  font-family: pdark;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #A5B2FB;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 11%;
  text-align:center;
 }

 .SN1
 {
  padding-right: 30.2%;
  padding-left: 11.6%;
 }

 .SN2
 {
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 0%;
 }

 .TI3
 {
  margin-left: 1.4%;
 }

 .ST4
 {
  padding-left: 3.7%;
 }

 .ST5
 {
  font-family: earthorbitersemital;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#e0c6f7;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.1%;
 }

 .Cell2
 {
  padding-left: 1.5%;
 }

 .Cell1
 {
  padding-left: 7.5%;
 }

 .pula
 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
 }

 .TDs1
 {
  background-image: url(../Imagens/Fundo1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 #stt1
 {
  text-align:center;
  font-family: pdark;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #A5B2FB;
 }

 .TI
 {
  margin-left: 1%;
 }

 .letr
 {
  font-family: earthorbitersemital;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#e0c6f7;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
 }

 .txtb
 {
  padding-left: 13.5%;
 }




 .Tds2
 {
  background-image: url(../Imagens/Fundop.png);
  background-size: 0 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .stt3
 {
  font-family: pdark;
  font-size: 0;
  color: #A5B2FB;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 0;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 0;
  text-align:center;
 }

 .SN12
 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .TI32
 {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .ST52
 {
  font-family: earthorbitersemital;
  font-size: 0;
  color:#e0c6f7;
  width: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
 }

 .Cell22
 {
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .Cell12
 {
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .TI32
 {
  width: 0%;
 }
}



/* 
Estilos unicos do mobile
*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) and (max-height: 700px)
{
 div.bar
 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
 }

 .txtb
 {
  padding-left: 0%;
 } 

 .Tds2
 {
  background-image: url(../Imagens/Fundop.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .stt3
 {
  font-family: pdark;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #A5B2FB;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-right: 0;
  text-align:center;
 }

 .SN12
 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .TI32
 {
  width: 90%;
 }

 .ST52
 {
  font-family: earthorbitersemital;
  font-size: 19px;
  color:#e0c6f7;
  margin-left: 5%;
 }

 .Tds
 {
  display: none;
 }

 .Tds1
 {
  display: none;
 }

}
```

```html
<doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>WJ Photos </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/teste.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="Bar">
    <p class="txtb"><a href="#Sist">Sistemas</a></p>

    <p class="txtb"><a href="TDSC.html">Corpos celestiais</a></p>

    <p class="txtb">Criaturas</p>

    <p class="txtb">Sobre</p>
 </div>

 <div class="sla2">
 <div id="sla1">
  <div id="sla">
   <p id="Ti">No Man's Sky registros</p>

   <p>Este site tem meus ultimos registros sobre o jogo No Man's Sky</p>

   <p id="Ti1">No Man's Sky é sobre explorar e sobreviver em uma galáxia infinita gerada processualmente</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>


 <a name="Sist">
 <p id="st5"> Sistemas descobertos</p>

 <div class="TDs">
  <div class="stt">
   <p class="SN1">Nosmidi-Kur XVI</p>
   <p class="SN2">Aehola-Minusc V</p>
  </div>

   <div class="TI1">
    <img class="TI3" src="Imagens/SIS1.jpg" width="47.4%">
    <img class="TI3" src="Imagens/SIS2.jpg" width="47.4%">
   </div>

 <div class="ST4">
  <table class="ST5">
   <tr>
    <td>Corpos celestiais:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">4 planetas</td>
    <td class="Cell1">Corpos celestiais:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">4 planetas e 1 lua</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Raça dominante:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">Gek</td>
    <td class="Cell1">Raça dominante:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">Korvax</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Economia:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">Mercantil(Estado: Confortável)</td>
    <td class="Cell1">Economia:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">Matemático(Estado: Sustentável)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Nível de conflito:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">Pacífico</td>
    <td class="Cell1">Nível de conflito:</td>
    <td class="Cell2">Inofensivo</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 </div>

 <p class="pula"></p>

 <div class="TDs1">
  <p id="stt1">Ubliku IX</p>
  <table class="TI">
   <td rowspan="4"><img src="Imagens/SIS3.jpg" width="100%"></td>
   <td class="letr">Corpos celestiais:       6 planetas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="letr">Raça dominante:       Gek</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="letr">Economia:       Experimental(Estado: Falhando)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="letr">Nível de conflito:       Estável</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

 <div class="asd">
 <div class="TDs2">
  <div class="stt3">
   <p class="SN12">Nosmidi-Kur XVI</p>
   <img class="TI32" src="Imagens/SIS1.jpg">
    <table class="ST52">
     <td>Corpos celestiais:</td>
     <td>4 planetas</td>
     <tr>
     <td>Raça dominante:</td>
     <td>Gek</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Economia:</td>
     <td>Mercantil(Confortável)</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Nível de conflito:</td>
     <td>Pacífico</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

 </a>
</body>
```

[Imagem de fundo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F71pW.jpg)

[Imagem de exemplo para todos os itens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzGs3.jpg)

(Se utilizei algum termo errado ou algo do tipo, me desculpe, sou novo na area, programo a so um mes, ainda me falta pratica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione as seguintes tags em seu HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Comment: Muiiito obrigado vei, aleluia uma solução, pqp